# java background process ended without error message

Tags: java, ubuntu, process, kill

I have a small java server listening on port 10299 for performing some image processing on demand. I start the program as follows:

```
java -Xms15m -Xmx25m -jar /tools/image-server.jar > /tools/image-server.log &
```

After an indeterminate period of time the process gets killed whithout any error message (or at least i haven't discovered any...). The OS is Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS.

The code itself seems to be working fine, since it is running without error on my other machine.

What could cause the unexpected ending of the program?
Is it possible to check which process killed the program?
Which log files could I check?

Comment: I'd recommend redirecting the error stream too (>&), so that anything written there that may show the error gets saved.

Comment: Try running the server using the `nohup` commmand (`man nohup`). Maybe -Xmx25m is not enough memory?

Comment: @GyroGearless Thanks. Running it with `nohup` seems to work. I don't think it's a memory issue though (the machine has enough and the program also terminated when there was no action). Would you suggest using `nohup` even if I have no clue why the program is terminated? @kiheru still no error output.